# Files not visible after upload from pc

Tags: file-transfer

My phones have same issue i don't know if i do something wrong or what but after I connect my phone to pc and upload some files you are not able to see them on phone.

Example i upload new.apk to Downloads folder and disconnect my phone. Then going to Download folder on phone but file is not there. However if you go trough file explorer you can see file there. 
Also same issue if i connect phone to pc and delete files. After disconnect and going to that folder files are still there but if you go trough file explorer wont be there.

Comment: Which OS do you use on your PC? You may be affected by a bug in the used MTP protocol via USB (on PC and/or phone side). Try to reboot the device and see if the files re-appear or use on of the commands presented in this answer:https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241

Comment: I have windows 10 on pc , reboot did not helped

Comment: The media storage database may be corrupt. Try to clear the app data of the "Media Storage" app (`com.android.providers.media`) and reboot your device. Then missing files should be visible.