# How to find screeshots from PC?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, files, screenshots

I'm looking for a screenshot, which I can see in Google Photos under *Device folders* -> *Screeshots*.

But when I browse it from my PC (Windows 10), in *DCIM* folder I can only see *Camera* one (I read it should be *Screenshots* next to it).

Why is that? Is it possible that I don't have permissions to see it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case screenshots were actually located under *Pictures/Screenshots*.

Yet for some reason this directory wasn't visible when I was connected in (I believe default) *Transfer files* mode.

When I switched to **Transfer Photos (PTP)** , the *Screenshots* folder became visible from file browser.

To change, I needed to click on notification *USB for file transfer*, which popped up on my phone.

Comment: Most likely if you switch back to "Transfer files / MTP" mode the screenshots will also be visible.

Comment: @Robert that is right, why is that?

Comment: This question is quite common. See for example [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241).