# Viewing files on Android phone from computer, only showing DCIM and Pictures folders, in internal shared storage

Tags: file-system

I have phones running Android..

When I connect either one to my computer, and click "internal shared storage", I only see DCIM and Pictures..

But if I go to any decent file manager app on the phone then it shows far more folders within "internal shared storage" e.g. Download, and other folders.

One of my phones, comes with what looks like a nice app for backing up, and it creates a folder with the backup, and I want to copy that folder to my computer. But I cant see how to access that folder to copy it onto my computer!

I'd be a little bit surprised if this is a situation where the phone has to be rooted to do it.. I do plan to, but this is an app that the phone comes with. So some may backup the phone before unlocking the bootloader.

Comment: Please read this question and answer for details why not all files and folder are visible at the moment from the PC https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202728/why-my-dcim-folder-is-empty-seen-in-the-computer-but-not-empty-in-the-phone

Comment: so in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GitMOYdsA9I  where he shows here https://i.imgur.com/9gou0yT.png  windows explorer showing lots more folders than just DCIM and Pictures, he must have run a command like that suggested at your link to do it?

Comment: I've just tried on Nexus 5 (Lineage OS 14.1, Android 7.1.2), looks like the USB connection mode was set to Transfer Photos (PTP) and thus only showing DCIM and Pictures? Can you try Transfer Files (MTP) mode to show more folders?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, I think you're right.. my Moto phone doesn't have an MTP option but it has a "file transfer" option which is probably the same thing, and that shows all more folders.  My oneplus phone has some strange issue that this guy seems to face https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/usb-file-transfer-not-working.1054546/ where you choose file transfer and double click the thing and it shows nothing at all

Comment: If file transfer mode is screwed on your device you can still use `adb` to pull files from your device via comand-line. Just enable developer options on your device and adb. On PC side install Android SDK or minimal ADB environment.