# Ghost files on sd card

Tags: google-play-store, internal-sd, 8.1-oreo

About the first problem: so, once out of nowhere the files on my old sd card got corrupted. I decided to pull in and out tge sd card, without safely ejecting it first, which corrupted it completely. So I got a new sd card, and every time I prepare it for usage,android asks me to move 1.47 GB of files to free up space. If I do, 1.47 GB gets magically added to the amount of occupied space on my SD card to the "apps" category, however no apps are visible themselves. I've reformatted the card several times, changed it from internal storage to portable and back, the ghost files are still there. My guess is that the apps that were previously on my sd card themselves got erased, but the system saved their weight and the directories they were in.

There's another problem, with google play. Basically it completely ignores the existence of my sd card, even though it's formatted as internal storage.

I'd greatly appreciate any solution to atleast one of the problems I've mentioned, because I'm completely lost, even after days of trying to find solutions. Also I think I should note that it's impossible for me to get a card reader for my pc in the nearest future.

Comment: "*however no apps are visible themselves*". Where do you expect them to be visible? // How do you know that Play Store ignores the existence of your SD card? // Is your device rooted?

Comment: Android populates a database which contains all files. May be this database is out of sync  and Android does not update it because of a bug. In the end [resetting the mediastore database](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241) may help you.

Comment: You could try to enable adb and use the command `pm trim-caches` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25631612/150978 Hopefully it recovers the lost storage.