# Path of "Documents & other" in Google Pixel 4a "Files" app

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, google-pixel

I copied, via USB file transfer, a small folder (3 small files) into `This PC\Pixel 4a\Internal shared storage\Documents`.

I thought that using `Files by Google` (version 1.0.459878599) > `Documents & other`, I could access the files in that folder using my smartphone when disconnected from PC.

I was surprised not to see neither the folder, nor the files:

[image: Files by Google, Documents & other]

If I scroll down that app's windows to `Internal storage`, then select `Documents`, I can then see my subfolder along with the 3 files. But this is inconvenient.

**What is the path to `Documents & other` in Google Pixel 4a's `Files` app?**

**Update:** I currently workaround this by marking the 3 files as "Favorite". They then show up in the `Favorites` collection. Single touch only (but still need to scroll down).

Comment: I have the opposite situation: My "Documents" folder is empty `Documents & other` on my device shows a list of PDF and ZIP files on the shared storage without any directory structure. Not sure what other file extensions are also considered as "Document". But it is clear that this section is totally unrelated to the "Documents" folder.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I am still confused as how do I transfer files from my PC so that they are visible in `Documents & other`. Any idea? Could it be dependent on some daily service that searches internal storage and populates that mysterious `Documents & other`?

Comment: Android has the internal MediaStore database which "indexes" all documents on shared storage. See also my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241 Depending on what you transfer (and how many files) it may take some time until the file are indexed by the MediaStore database. One known problem of this database are defect files (on some devices/Android versions the indexer can stop or crash). So make sure not to upload defect files.

Comment: What kind of files are they? Observing my Files on Pixel 3a, only CSV and PDF files but not folders are shown there (I rarely store files though, those are the only limited files I have on the phone), but the paths can be anywhere (e.g. Download folder, `/BarcodeScanner` folder by [ZXing Team](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android), etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the path to `Documents & other` in Google Pixel 4a's Files app?

Files app when selecting `Documents & other` does not show a specific path/folder at all. Instead it uses the Android internal Media Store database for all files within the shared storage that have are recorded in this database and that have a certain file type (respectively file extension).

File Types that are shown in the `Documents & other`:

- TXT
- PDF
- CSV
- ZIP
- ODP
- DOC
- DOCX
- EPUB
- ...

If you want to look at files within `Documents` folder in your shared storage folder you have to scroll down and select `Internal storage` and then `Documents` (or use the Favorites workaround that you have mentioned).

The following files are For example files like PDF files, CSV