# Windows Explorer does not show files in Android filesystem

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I am using a tablet with Android version 8.1.0

I save files into internal memory using my app which get saved at `/storage/emulated/0/FOLDER/filename.txt`

Doing `adb shell ls -la sdcard/FOLDER` in windows cmd shows correct contents of this folder as well

However, when opening this location in Windows Explorer (shows up as `This PC\DTABC2\Internal shared storage\FOLDER` on windows 10), the files I created are not there. It shows some files and directories that actually exist (also shown in `adb shell`), but it also shows previous files I had created and deleted (using `adb shell rn`) few days ago (double clicking these files show an error, other files that also show up on `adb shell` open normally). It's not showing any of the other new files created today

Normally when this happens with my other devices I pull out the USB connector and reconnect the device to PC, and windows explorer starts showing the correct content. However with this tablet windows explorer is not showing updated content for reason, and shows the same files every time I reconnect. I have used windows explorer to copy files on and off this tablet, so it wasn't always like this before, but I have been saving files from my app and pulling and deleting using adb more recently

Why is it behaving this way, and ho do I force windows to show the latest contents in the tablet's memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my DCIM folder is empty seen in the computer but not empty in the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202728/2241). On Old Android versions (AFAIR Android 9 and older) Android expects that the app informs the OS/MediaService about newly created or modified files. Newer Android versions automatically detect those changes. To force re-detection you can reboot the phone as simple workaround.