The subfolder under the Download folder is missing
Use the android file manager,Open the menu on the left,On the right side of the Download folder.
After I clicked the unload button, the file was still there and all the subfolders were gone.
Path: /storage/emulated/0/Download
Neither the file manager nor the PC can see them.
The device is not root，The system is Android 12.
Can I still get them back? Thanks!
step:

Please close the question,It's a little complicated.

Thanks for the reply, language is indeed an issue.

The file manager and the PC both may not show the real file-system, instead they only show the files indexed by MediaStore database. See my answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241 If you want to see the real file-system use a File manager app and grant it the Manage files permission manually in settings or use adb shell from a PC to get a Linux shell where you can list files in the file-system.
