In Samsung's My Files app, "Documents" category doesn't show all documents in "Documents" folder
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A14 running Android 14. In Samsung's My Files app, I have some categories, and when I click on "Documents", I cannot see all documents listed in the "Documents" subfolder of the internal storage ("Stockage Interne" on the screenshot).



Why? Are there 2 document folders with different content?

Perhaps you should give examples of documents that you cannot see

Most likely the "Documents" category is populated from the Android MediaStore Database, an Android internal database that (should) contains entries for every file in your shared storage.
That database is normally kept automatically in sync with your file-system but sometimes the indexing task hangs or new files are missed by the indexing task, then you have the database view and the real file-system view which can be different.
On older Android versions (before Android 9) the MediaStore Database was often not in sync with the file-system. On newer Android versions this doesn't happen often anymore. However things like defect files can make the indexing system go wild and then it can miss new files.
To make the MediaStore Database to be in sync again there are two options: rebuild from scratch or force it to update itself.
For more details see also an old answer of me: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202739/2241

Robert's answer has explained how MediaStore works and how sometimes it might fail to scan. Another possibility is that not all files located in the "Documents" folder are considered documents.
The "Documents" category lists all documents from everywhere, not only from the "Documents" folder. On the other hand, not all files located in the "Documents" folder are automatically considered as documents.
Based on observation on Samsung Galaxy M12 running Android 13, the "Documents" category contains files of type: TXT, PDF, CSV, DOCX, XLSX (not an exhaustive list). Thus, files with other types inside the "Documents" folder may not be listed in the "Documents" category.
